# Align image within a div with other div

Tags: html, css

I have two div's A and B. The div A width is auto and the div B width is set to a specifically value wich is smaller than the browser window width. The div B is also in the middle of the browser window.

Within div A I have an image. What I want is that the image be always aligned with div B, even when I resize the browser window.

[image]

```css
#header {
  background-color: #761D1F;
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
  margin: -8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#div-body {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#img {
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img id="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
</div>

<div id="div-body">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: is there any difficulty in hardcoding the margin-left or padding-left values?

Comment: Add `padding-left: 48px;`  to `#div-body` (same value as `margin-left` on `#img`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the `img` in another `div` and apply the same CSS to div B and the wrapper.

```css
#header {
  background-color: #761D1F;
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
  margin: -8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#div-body, #image-wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#img {
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="image-wrapper">
    <img id="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="div-body">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Works great, but I would recommend putting `max-height: 100%;` in the styles of `#div-body, #image-wrapper`, because this way you can avoid any possible future issue of element overflow in the header.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I have different background colors in div A and B, and after apply this solution, part of div A gets the same background color of div B.

Comment: You could create two rules: One which selects div B and the wrapper and sets the width, etc. and another rule which selects only div B and sets the background color.

Answer (score 2):

So you have `#div-body`, which is 1100px wide and aligned so it's always in the middle of your screen. What you want to use to determine the margin that the `img` should have to be perfectly aligned with `#div-body` is `calc`. This means the margin should be 50% of the screen minus half of `#div-body` (50% - 550px). so in your CSS:

```css
#header {
  background-color: #761D1F;
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
  margin: -8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#div-body {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
#img {
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 550px); /* THIS IS CHANGED*/
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img id="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/Singapore_Road_Signs_-_Information_Sign_-_One-way_traffic_ahead.svg" height="150px;">
</div>

<div id="div-body">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: The calc() function in css is a really good alternative, but you should have in mind that it may be incompatible with some older browsers. So, if you are thinking on doing something cross-browser it won't be the best way to do this. [See here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: This is true, you can check out the compatability here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Exactly the same link I've posted :)

Comment: Oops sorry, i didn't see the link :)